# Existe um setBackgroud no AppWigetProvider?

Tags: android

A minha duvida é se existe o método `setBackground` na classe do `AppWidgetProvider`?

Se for possível utilizar o método na class tem algum caminho que posso seguir?

Estou desenvolvendo um widget nativo.

Comment: Se possível poste seu código

Comment: @JoãoVitor ele pediu o codigo para entender a necessidade de uso, para acaso entender ele puder dar uma solução alternativa que sirva para o seu caso, entende?

Comment: "ja consigo usar setViewResource". E qual seu código? Já olhou na documentação (provavelmente não)? Está usando Xamarin ou Java? Olha quantas perguntas.... Sua pergunta está bastante ampla, pode ser tão ampla, pode acabar sendo fechada.

Answer (score 2):

A resposta da minha pergunta é sim tem uma forma utilizando o seguinte codigo é possivel setar o background do widget.

```
view.setInt(R.id.exec_cena,"setBackgroundResource",R.drawable.button_effect);
```